# q = filter('city =', 'Seattle' or 'Osaka') correct or not?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to find all customers who come from Seattle or Osaka. Is it correct?

```
q = Customer.all()
q = filter('city =', 'Seattle' or 'Osaka')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You want

```
q.filter('city IN', ['Seattle','Osaka'])
```